# What's the correct form of this question?

Tags: questions, politeness

I would like to know, what's the respectful format of this question: ( Business context )

- Can we have a call?
- Could we have a call?
- Can I call you?
- Can I meet with you?
- Could I meet with you?

Comment: More context is needed. In a business context either of the first two would make sense. But I wouldn't use that same structure in a personal context.

Comment: Yes , what I would like to know ina business context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as commented by others, more information is needed to give good answer but generally when you are using "can" as a permission, the past form as in "Could I meet with you?" is considered to be more polite and formal also if you want to be more formal you can use "may" instead of "can" or "could". Also it might be better not to use "can" in a business context, since it considered to be somewhat informal.